# Weird scoping issue with method parameters and "using" statement

Tags: c#, .net

I just ran into a weird scope issue with method parameters in C# and I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on why this is happening or whether it's a bug.

My code essentially is this:

```
void MyMethod(SqlHelper db, int myInt)
{
    try
    {
        using (db)
        {
            var bar = OtherMethod(myInt);
```

On the last line, myInt is throwing an error: "Cannot use local variable 'myInt' before it is declared"

This doesn't throw an error:

```
void MyMethod(SqlHelper db, int myInt)
{
    try
    {
        var foo = myInt;
        using (db)
        {
```

And my workaround for now is:

```
void MyMethod(SqlHelper db, int myInt)
{
    var foo = myInt;
    try
    {
        using (db)
        {
            var bar = OtherMethod(foo);
```

But why is this happening? How is myInt falling outside of the scope of the using statement?? I feel personally attacked.

My project is in .Net Framework 4.7.

**EDIT:** I can't actually reproduce this with the slimmed down version I presented. I will do more research. Thanks to everyone who helped.

**EDIT 2:** As everyone noted, I left out too much information and the error couldn't be replicated. I found the issue and will leave it here because I am dumb and maybe it will help someone.
Relevant code was this:

```
void MyMethod(SqlHelper db, int myInt)
{
    try
    {
        using (db = new SqlHelper())
        {
            var bar = OtherMethod(myInt);
            var myInt = SomeMethod(bar);
```

I had declared another variable with the same name further down within the using statement and Visual Studio didn't like that but didn't know how to tell me. What a day. Thanks again to everyone who came with me on this journey.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - it'll be much easier to help you that way. (I'd also suggest that formatting C# according to "the Visual Studio default" (brace on a line on its own) is likely to make it a bit easier for most readers here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: When you say 'throwing and error' do you mean gives a compilation error, or throws an exception?

Comment: Thanks I'll make those updates. By error I mean compilation error.

Comment: On a side note, I think I would avoid disposing a method parameter (i.e. `using (db)`).

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I found the issue and I appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce the error but was not successful, meaning the unit test that I created works. It compiles and it does not throw any exception. Thus, you would have to provide some more information for us to reproduce the error.

```cs
        private void MyMethod(IDisposable db, int myInt)
        {
            try
            {
                using (db)
                {
                    int bar = OtherMethod(myInt);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Do something with the exception.
                throw;
            }
        }

        private int OtherMethod(int myInt)
        {
            return myInt;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            MyMethod(new MemoryStream(), 10);
        }
```

Note that passing the `SqlHelper` as a parameter and then putting that in the`using` statement is not a good practice. You should avoid that.

Comment: You're right, I went to reproduce it outside of my code and I can't either. Thanks for trying!

Comment: I figured out the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

One very odd thing you are doing is withyour `using` statement. You are putting a `using` on `db`, an object that someone else has created and passed into this method. When the code leaves your `using` block it will be disposed and whoever created it will not be able to use it, even though the expect to.

Generally objects should be put in a `using` block when they are created:

```
using (var db = new SqlHelper())
{
    ...
}
```

Not sure if that's the cause of you're problem, though.

Comment: Yeah I trimmed the fat to present the issue but as noted I can't actually reproduce the issue when I do that. May just need to restart visual studio, I'm not sure. Thank you!